# Programmatically change datelimit in JQUERY calendar control

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I seem to be having a problem setting the dateLimit of the JQuery calendar control, programatically.

When the page initially load, I setup the calendar control like so:

```
$('#dashboard-report-range').daterangepicker({
                opens: (App.isRTL() ? 'right' : 'left'),
                startDate: moment($('#hidLatestData_Date').val()).add('days', -6),
                endDate: moment($('#hidLatestData_Date').val()),//.add('days', 1),
                minDate: '01/01/2012',
                maxDate: moment($('#hidLatestData_Date').val()),//.add('days', 2),
                dateLimit: {
                    days: 6
                },
                showDropdowns: false,
                showWeekNumbers: true,
                timePicker: false,
                timePickerIncrement: 1,
                timePicker12Hour: true,
                ranges: {
                    'Today': [moment(), moment().add('days', 0)],
                    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1).add('days', 0)],
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()]//,
                    //'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
                    //'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                    //'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
                },
                buttonClasses: ['btn'],
                applyClass: 'blue',
                cancelClass: 'default',
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                separator: ' to ',
                locale: {
                    applyLabel: 'Apply',
                    fromLabel: 'From',
                    toLabel: 'To',
                    customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
                    daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
                    monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                    firstDay: 1
                }
            }
```

On the page, I have a drop down list. If a specific selection is made, I want to change the dateLimit value to 1, rather than 6.

I have tried a bunch of different options, but nothing seems to be working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am actually having to change the start time too, but the code for (below) works 100% correctly.

```
$("#dashboard-report-range").datepicker('option', { startDate: new Date(hidEndDate)});
```

These are the options I have tried, plus others I cannot even remember anymore:

```
    $("#dashboard-report-range").datepicker('option', { dateLimit: "days:1"});

$("#dashboard-report-range").datepicker('option', { dateLimit: { "days":"1"}});

$("#dashboard-report-range").datepicker('option',  dateLimit: { "days":"1"});

$("#dashboard-report-range").datepicker('option', dateLimit: "days:1");

$("#dashboard-report-range").datepicker('option', dateLimit, "days:1");

$("#dashboard-report-range").datepicker('option',  "dateLimit", "days:1"  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
$("#dashboard-report-range").datepicker('option',  "dateLimit.days", "1"  );
```

**Update 1:**

You can access datarangepicker data in following manner:

```
var drp = $('#dashboard-report-range').data('daterangepicker');
drp.dateLimit.days = 1;
```

**Update 2:**

You can also update properties in following manner:

```
drp.ranges['Today'] = [moment(), moment().add('days', 1)]
```

Here is updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pvskz78d/3/

Comment: perhaps more specifically, how would I select one of the predefined ranges, programatically?

Comment: that ranges code is great, but how would I select one of my pre-defined ranges? By default, it is set to last 7 days, how would I change to to select "Today"?

Comment: Daterangepicker has internal function (clickRange) which is used when you select options from the UI. You can set startDate and endDate at creation time, or you can update them manually whenever using setStartDate() and setEndDate() functions. I am not sure how to invoke that function via code. I tried something like this: `$(".ranges ul li:contains('Last 7 Days')").click();` but that would only select that range and not update UI.

Comment: I contacted the developer of this, and here is his reply: You should recreate the picker with the desired options rather than modifying its internal state. You can call $.daterangepicker(options) over and over; it destroys the current date picker and makes a new one with those options.

    $('#dashboard-report-range').daterangepicker({ dateLimit: 1, startDate: hidEndDate, ... });

"Custom Range" will be highlighted when your startDate and endDate options don't match any other predefined range.

Comment: just one more comment though... turns out the authors solution was not working for me. This was due to the fact that I was running version 1.2. I have since upgraded to the latest version and his code works perfectly!